# Widget getting pushed behind Status Bar in Custom App Bar

Tags: flutter

I'm currently trying to make my `appBar` appear like the picture below but seem to be running into one particular issue every time I try doing so.

[image]

I have given the `appBar` a height of 100 and my idea was to distribute the height in a 40 60 ratio between the two Containers(amber and red). Things look fine when there's only the amber `Container` but as soon as I try adding the red `Container`, the amber `Container` somehow gets pushed up behind the status bar and I have no idea what is causing this.

This is till the point things look great with the amber `Container`

[image]

This is when the above anomaly occurs

[image]

This is my code. (the part commented out is the design for the Red Container)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeScreenState createState() => HomeScreenState();
}

class HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  bool _toggleDropDown = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(100),
        child: AppBar(
            elevation: 0,
            // backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            titleSpacing: 0,
            title: Column(
              children: [
                Container(                  //Amber Container
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 40,
                  color: Colors.amber,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                        height: 15,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        // color: Colors.red,
                        child: const Text(
                          'Delivering To',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 15),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 25,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                        // color: Colors.blue,
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            const Text(
                              'Current Location',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(width: 20),
                            Container(
                                height: double.infinity,
                                width: 20,
                                // color: Colors.yellow,
                                child: InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _toggleDropDown = !_toggleDropDown;
                                    });
                                  },
                                  child: Icon(
                                    !_toggleDropDown
                                        ? Icons.keyboard_arrow_down
                                        : Icons.keyboard_arrow_up,
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                  ),
                                ))
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                // Container(                //Red Container
                //   height: 60,
                //   width: double.infinity,
                //   color: Colors.red,
                //   padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
                //   child: Row(
                //     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                //     crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                //     children: [
                //       InkWell(
                //           onTap: () {},
                //           child: Icon(
                //             Icons.search,
                //             size: 25,
                //           )),
                //       Row(
                //         children: [
                //           InkWell(
                //             onTap: () {},
                //             child: const Icon(
                //               Icons.shopping_cart_outlined,
                //               color: Colors.white,
                //               size: 25,
                //             ),
                //           ),
                //           InkWell(
                //             onTap: () {},
                //             child: const Icon(
                //               Icons.notifications_none_outlined,
                //               color: Colors.white,
                //               size: 25,
                //             ),
                //           )
                //         ],
                //       )
                //     ],
                //   ),
                // )
              ],
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

FYI : I have also tried wrapping the Scaffold with SafeArea and the output that produces looks like this:

[image]

Comment: wrap  `Scaffold` with `SafeArea`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Tried that already

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is here `AppBar` is not getting `height:100`. While using `PreferredSize` you can just use `Column` or just using `toolbarHeight: 100` on `AppBar`.

```dart
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(100),
        child: AppBar(
            elevation: 0,
            // backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            titleSpacing: 0,
            toolbarHeight: 100, //<this
```

Or just do

```dart
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
      elevation: 0,
      toolbarHeight: 100, //<this
```

Comment: I have another question. Since all this is happening within the AppBar, can I expect no trouble when this app is run on devices with different screen sizes?

Comment: I prefer using `LayoutBuilder` as parent, then control the inner height, I didn't face any issue while using `toolbarHeight` until now.  As on doc `Defines the height of the toolbar component of an AppBar.` therefore hope it won't cause any issue in future.

Answer (score 1):

The trick lies in wrapping your `Scaffold()` with a `SafeArea()` widget.

- Scaffold represents the whole screen of a device, each and every pixel of your screen.
- SafeArea takes into account notches, status bars, bottom navigation bars and bottom navigation buttons.

Here's a quick how-to:

```
class _MyScreenState extends State<DonationDetails> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(), //your ui components goes here
     ));
   }
}
```

**UPDATE TO YOUR USE CASE**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreenTest extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeScreenTestState createState() => HomeScreenTestState();
}

class HomeScreenTestState extends State<HomeScreenTest> {
  bool _toggleDropDown = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(100),
        child: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          leading: null,
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          titleSpacing: 0,
          title: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 40,
            color: Colors.amber,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                  height: 15,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  // color: Colors.red,
                  child: const Text(
                    'Delivering To',
                    style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 15),
                 ),
               ),
               Container(
                  height: 25,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                  // color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                    const Text(
                      'Current Location',
                       style: TextStyle(
                         color: Colors.grey, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 20),
                  Container(
                      height: double.infinity,
                      width: 20,
                      // color: Colors.yellow,
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _toggleDropDown = !_toggleDropDown;
                          });
                        },
                        child: Icon(
                          !_toggleDropDown
                              ? Icons.keyboard_arrow_down
                              : Icons.keyboard_arrow_up,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottom: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(80),
        child: Container(
          //Red Container
          height: 60,
          width: double.infinity,
          color: Colors.red,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.shopping_cart_outlined,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 25,
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.shopping_cart_outlined,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 25,
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.notifications_none_outlined,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 25,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please point out where exactly in my code I should apply this?

Comment: Scaffold has a `body:` parameter, `SafeArea()` goes there, and then the rest of your code goes into the child of `SafeArea()`

Comment: I will update the answer to fit your code, if you wait for a little bit

Comment: Yes, that's the thing. This entire stuff is happening inside my appBar.  Perhaps you might want to go through my code once?

Comment: that would be incredibly helpful

Comment: @coolhack7 I updated to your use case with minor improvements

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bottom` in 'AppBar'.
Move the **red `Container`** to `bottom` with `PreferredSize` widget as parent. like this.

```
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(100),
        child: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          // backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          titleSpacing: 0,
          title: Container(
            //Amber Container
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 40,
            color: Colors.amber,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                  height: 15,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  // color: Colors.red,
                  child: const Text(
                    'Delivering To',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 15),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 25,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                  // color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      const Text(
                        'Current Location',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.grey, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 20),
                      Container(
                          height: double.infinity,
                          width: 20,
                          // color: Colors.yellow,
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                _toggleDropDown = !_toggleDropDown;
                              });
                            },
                            child: Icon(
                              !_toggleDropDown
                                  ? Icons.keyboard_arrow_down
                                  : Icons.keyboard_arrow_up,
                              color: Colors.red,
                            ),
                          ))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          bottom: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(80),
            child: Container(
              //Red Container
              height: 60,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.red,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  InkWell(
                      onTap: () {},
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.search,
                        size: 25,
                      )),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: const Icon(
                          Icons.shopping_cart_outlined,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: 25,
                        ),
                      ),
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: const Icon(
                          Icons.notifications_none_outlined,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: 25,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```